# HSQLDB 2.3.3: How to create a custom type?

Tags: hsqldb

How do I create a custom type in hsqldb?

```
create TYPE MY_CUSTOM_TYPE AS OBJECT (
   ID NUMERIC, 
   IDSTRING VARCHAR(100), 
   IDBINARY LONGVARBINARY, 
   DATE_CREATED TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define an object (structure) type in HSQLDB.